# Xcode 7.3.1: Schemes with duplicate configurations fail to import bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode7

Possible Duplicate: [Xcode 7.2 Failed to import bridging header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642866/xcode-7-2-failed-to-import-bridging-header)

I'm trying to setup `Staging` and `Production` environments with the help of `xCode schemes`. For that I made two new `configurations` in my project file by duplicating existing `debug` and `release` configurations. The new configurations are called `debugStaging` and `releaseStaging`. Then I made a new `scheme` and edited it to use newly created `configurations`. Without anything further when I try to run project with newly created scheme I get errors that my `Objective-C` header is not found. You can see overview of newly created scheme in following picture.

[image: scheme overview]

And the errors that I get:

[image: errors with new scheme]

Cleaning project or deleting Derived Data didn't help either but the app runs fine with original scheme. . Can someone point out something which i'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: same here in 2019, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: same here in 2020, Any update with this?